# Not getting correct subtraction result for difference of two images in python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

This is my python code where i want to find difference between two images.

```
import cv
import numpy as np
img1=cv.imread('/storage/emulated/0/a.jpg',0)
print(img1[0:1])
img2=img1
img2[0:1994]=1
print(img2[0:1])
rows,cols=img1[0:1].shape
print(rows)
print(cols)
rows,cols=img2[0:1].shape
print(rows)
print(cols)
print(np.subtract(img1[0:1,0:1], img2[0:1,0:1]))
```

I am subtracting these numpy arrays but getting zero always. Kindly help regarding this matter.

Comment: Are you trying to make a "copy" of `img1` and assign it to `img2`?  `img2=img1` will not do that.  As it stands they both reference the same object -- so it makes sense that the difference is zero.  [`np.copy()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) (or even reading the file a second time if you *really* have to) is likely what you want.

Comment: As stated already, it looks like you are just subtracting the same image from itself which of course will result in zero. Read in a second image and assign it to `img2` instead of `img2 = img1` and that should given you your desired result.

Comment: Sir, actually i made the img2 as copy of img1.  But then i reassigned the img2 with all pixel having one. Hence there should be some difference.

Comment: Use `img2 = img1.copy() `

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the way you have copied the image.

When you assign an object using the assignment operator (=), the changes made on one object will be reflected in the other image as well. So your this case when you do `img2 = img1` the changes made in `img2` are reflected in `img1` also. Hence upon subtraction you are *getting zero always*.

A quick fix would be to use `copy()` method. This creates a new object `img2` all together. Hence changes made in `img2` will not be reflected in `img1` and vice-versa.

```
img2 = img1.copy()
```

Now printing `print(np.subtract(img1[0:1,0:1], img2[0:1,0:1]))` yields me `[[233]]`

Have look at [THIS BLOG POST](https://realpython.com/copying-python-objects/) also.